# How to make Laravel Nova like Fields

Tags: php, laravel, class, static

I wanna create class for making fields, but in Laravel Nova this classes called like `Text::make()->placeholder()` and etc. This means that methods inside that class is static.

This is my field class:

```
class Field
{
   private $field = [];

   public function set($key, $value)
   {
      $this->field[$key] = $value;
   }

   public function get()
   {
      return $this->field;
   }
}

class Text
{
   private static $field;

   public static function make($name)
   {
      self::$field = new Field;

      self::$field->set('@saturn_type', 'string');
      self::$field->set('@saturn_key', $name);
      self::$field->set('@saturn_field', 'text');

      return new Text;
   }

   public function placeholder($value)
   {
      self::$field->set('placeholder', $value);
      return $this;
   }

   public function required()
   {
      self::$field->set('required', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function translate()
   {
      self::$field->set('translate', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function wysiwyg()
   {
      self::$field->set('wysiwyg', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function get()
   {
      return (array) self::$field->get();
   }
}
```

and this is how i call it:

```
$fields = [
    Text::make('name')->placeholder('Full Name'),
    Text::make('email')->placeholder('Email'),
    Text::make('password')->placeholder('Password'),
]

$lastArray = $fields->map(function ($field) {
      return $field->get();
   }
);
```

But when i call get() method for each item in this array to get array, each item returns the last item's name and placeholder because it is static. How can i solve this.

Comment: Is there any functional reason why you'd want it to be static?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Actually my friend Nijat found ))

```
class Field
{
   private $field = [];

   public function set($key, $value)
   {
      $this->field[$key] = $value;
   }

   public function get()
   {
      return $this->field;
   }
}

class Text
{
   private $field;

   public function __construct($name)
   {
      $this->field = new Field;

      $this->field->set('@saturn_type', 'string');
      $this->field->set('@saturn_key', $name);
      $this->field->set('@saturn_field', 'text');
   }

   public static function make($name)
   {
      return new Text($name);
   }

   public function placeholder($value)
   {
      $this->field->set('placeholder', $value);
      return $this;
   }

   public function required()
   {
      $this->field->set('required', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function translate()
   {
      $this->field->set('translate', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function wysiwyg()
   {
      $this->field->set('wysiwyg', true);
      return $this;
   }

   public function get()
   {
      return (array) $this->field->get();
   }
}
```

You just have to create constructor then call it in static method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Text` inherit from `Field` and have a much simpler `make` method:

```
class Field
{
    public static function make(...$arguments)
    {
        return new static(...$arguments);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This will instantiate the parent class (e.g. `Text`) and return it, allowing you to keep the chaining. In the methods you can then use `$this->` as usual (instead of `self::`). And move the content of `Text::make` to the constructor:

```
class Text extends Field
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->set('@saturn_type', 'string');
        $this->set('@saturn_key', $name);
        $this->set('@saturn_field', 'text');
    }

    // ...
}
```